# ARP Spoofing: Replying to requests meant for spoofed IP, while also being able to communicate with spoofed IP

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing, arp

I am simulating an ARP Spoofing attack on a local network. I have an Attacker machine on Linux, a web server, and a Victim machine which is trying to access the web server. I am successfully able to spoof the IP of the web server, and I am redirecting the Victim to the virtual web server on the Attacker machine. I made the Attacker respond to requests meant for the Victim, by doing `ip addr add <victim> dev <device>` on the Attacker machine.

However, I would like to have the Attacker machine be able to communicate with the web server I am trying to spoof. As of now, I am not able to, since the Attacker machine redirects the IP of the web server to localhost. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: How are you arp spoofing? The tool should have proxy settings. The concept you are looking for is "proxy".

Comment: Well, you certainly don't want to steal the IP address like you are doing. You aren't really ARP spoofing; I guess it's more of IP hijacking.